# Oracle SQL filter results between two dates, but only display records within a time range

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to display records between two dates, but they only want to see the records submitted within a time range as well.

My example SQL only filters the date and does not account for the Time.

For instance, they only want to see records between Jan 01, 2019 to Jan 03, 2019 if they AppRecvdDate Time is between 8pm and Midnight.
The example below, only ID 001, 002, 004 would be returned.

```
ID    AppRecvdDate
001   01-JAN-19 23:00
002   01-JAN-19 23:50
003   02-JAN-19 19:59
004   03-JAN-19 20:15
005   04-JAN-19 20:30

select id, apprecvddate
from application a
where a.apprecvddate between 
TO_DATE('01-JAN-2019 00:00:01', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
AND
TO_DATE( '03-JAN-2019 23:59:59',  'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: ... Despite the fact that the `DATE` type in oracle doesn't have fractional seconds, you should still be using an exclusive upper-bound for the condition (`< TO_DATE('04-JAN-2019 00:00:00',  'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')`.  For one thing, this is semantically more correct: "everything before January 4th".  It also makes it much easier to move to `TIMESTAMP`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Times are not supported as a first-class type in Oracle.  You could also write the time condition as:

```
where a.apprecvddate >= date '2019-01-01' and
      a.apprecvddate < date '2019-01-04' and
      to_char(a.apprecvddate, 'HH24:MI') >= '20:00'
```

Comment: ERROR at line 5:
ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source

Comment: @salazar44 . . . Like I say, Oracle does not support times very well.  The second method works.  `extract(hour)` will work with `timestamp`s but not `date`s, even though `date`s can store hours.  I wonder who designs these limitations?